# How do I authenticate to send a clickConversion to google Ads with a service account and over REST API with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-ads-api

I've tried with [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/auth) authenticate and with [this REST](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/reference/rest/v15/customers/uploadClickConversions) to send the conversion over REST API due to missing Typescript/Javascript-Client-Bib.

I am already failing at the authentication. I hope, if the authentication is working, the click conversion will be send. For the case I am guessing wrong, I extended the question. I hope the question is not to big. Blame me if I am wrong.

This is my error:
[image]

**My setup**
Regarding to the documentation I have a google ads account with a developer token. This token will be used, when I send the click conversion, as you can [see here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/auth#request_headers). The token has nothing to do with the authentication of the service account.
Therefore I have a service account on the Google Cloud Project, which also has the Google Ads Api enabled.
[image]

I also added to the workspace domain to the domain wide delegation the client id of the service account with the scope *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords*
[image]
This created in the category **APIs & Services** also an **OAuth 2.0 Client IDs**
[image]
The clientIds are fitting as well.

Just in case I also added an OAuth consent screen with the scope *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords* with the Testing status and external. But I don't think I will need this with a service account.

The service account itself has no further related rights. The documentation don't give me the info, that the service account need further rights. My thoughts: I added the client id to the domain wide delegation, this should be enough. I hope I am wrong here.

Now everything should be set up. I hope I didn't miss a step.

**My guess:**
Either I am missing some rights. Or I missunderstand the refresh token in the function authenticateToGoogleAdsManager. I create a signed JWT. Google says here, I need a refresh token. But the authentication via `await fetch('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token'` just gives me an access token. So I thought I just need a jwt here.

This is the way I am executing my code (in a testcase. Service Account JSON and clickConversion are given.)

```js
 // First I create a signed jwt
    const jwt = generateJsonWebTokenForServiceAccount(
      serviceAccount,
      ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords'],
      'googleads'
    )

    // Then I use the signed jwt to authenticate to Google Ads Manager
    const authenticationResult = await authenticateToGoogleAdsManager(
      serviceAccount.client_id,
      serviceAccount.private_key,
      jwt
    )

    console.log(authenticationResult)

    // Then I use the access token to send a click conversion to Google Ads Manager
    const test = await sendClickConversionToGoogleAdsManager(
      CUSTOMERID,
      clickConversion,
      accessToken.access_token,
      'DEV-TOKEN'
    )
```

Here are my functions:

```js
/**
 * Generates a JSON Web Token (JWT) for a service account.
 *
 * @param serviceAccount - The service account object containing the client email and private key.
 * @param scopes - An array of scopes for which the token will be authorized.
 * @param serviceName - The name of the service for which the token will be authorized. Default is 'oauth2'.
 * @param expirationTimeInSeconds - The expiration time of the token in seconds. Default is 3600 seconds (1 hour).
 * @returns The generated JSON Web Token.
 */
export function generateJsonWebTokenForServiceAccount(
  serviceAccount: ServiceAccount,
  scopes: string[],
  serviceName: string = 'oauth2',
  expirationTimeInSeconds = 3600
) {
  const aud =
    serviceName === 'oauth2' ? 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' : `https://${serviceName}.googleapis.com/`
  const currentTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
  const expirationTimestamp = currentTimestamp + expirationTimeInSeconds

  const payload = {
    iss: serviceAccount.client_email,
    sub: serviceAccount.client_email,
    scope: scopes.join(' '),
    aud: aud,
    exp: expirationTimestamp,
    iat: currentTimestamp
  }

  const options: SignOptions = {
    algorithm: 'RS256'
  }

  return jwt.sign(payload, serviceAccount.private_key, options)
}

/**
 * Authenticates to Google Ads Manager using the provided credentials.
 * @param clientId The client ID for authentication.
 * @param clientSecret The client secret for authentication.
 * @param refreshToken The refresh token for authentication.
 * @returns A promise that resolves to the access token.
 */
export async function authenticateToGoogleAdsManager(
  clientId: string,
  clientSecret: string,
  refreshToken: string
): Promise<string> {
  const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token'
  const body = {
    client_id: clientId,
    client_secret: clientSecret,
    refresh_token: refreshToken,
    grant_type: 'refresh_token'
  }

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  })

  const data = await response.json()

  return data.access_token
}

/**
 * Sends a click conversion to Google Ads Manager.
 * 
 * @param customerId - The ID of the customer.
 * @param clickConversion - The click conversion data.
 * @param accessToken - The access token for authentication.
 * @param developerToken - The developer token for authentication.
 * @param options - Optional API options.
 * @returns A promise that resolves to void.
 */
export async function sendClickConversionToGoogleAdsManager(
  customerId: number,
  clickConversion: ClickConversion,
  accessToken: string,
  developerToken: string,
  options?: ApiOptions
): Promise<void> {
  const url = `https://googleads.googleapis.com/v15/customers/${customerId}:uploadClickConversions`

  if (!options) {
    options = {
      partialFailure: false,
      validateOnly: false,
      debugEnabled: false,
      jobId: 0
    }
  }

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      'developer-token': developerToken
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      conversions: [clickConversion],
      partialFailure: options.partialFailure,
      validateOnly: options.validateOnly,
      debugEnabled: options.debugEnabled,
      jobId: options.jobId
    })
  })

  const data = await response.json()
  return data
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've talked with the Google Ads API Support and the solution was, to [generate a refresh token with a google user via console](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/get-started/make-first-call#fetch_a_refresh_token). The google user must be part of the google ads manager account.
Then we use the refresh token to authenticate to google ads manager as mentioned in the method `authenticateToGoogleAdsManager`.

They didn't offer me a solution with the service account.